# Show that if $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, then $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil = \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{k} \rfloor + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is answer in the back of the book but it doesn't make sense to me:

1. There is some $b$ with $(b-1)k < n \leqslant bk$.
2. Hence, $(b-1)k \leqslant n-1 < bk$.
3. Divide by $k$ to obtain $b-1 < \frac{n}{k} \leqslant b$ and $b-1 \leqslant \frac{n - 1}{k} < b$.
4. Hence, $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil = b$ and $\lfloor \frac{n - 1}{k} \rfloor = b-1$.

Where did step one come from? What happened in step two? How did step three turn into step 4?

Comment: If that's really what's in the back of your book, someone was drinking-while-deriving. (2) makes no sense, and the 2nd part of (3) makes no sense.

Comment: What about now? Those were all typos. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $n$ is an integer, so you divide the positive real line into disjoint intervals

$$
 (0, k], (k, 2k], (2k, 3k], \cdots,
 $$

then $n$ must fall into one of them. In fact, this shows the existence of $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil$.

2) it meant to say that

$$
 (b - 1)k \leq n - 1 < bk,
 $$

since all of them are integers.

3) Now you divide all these inequalities by $k$.

4) That is the definition of ceil and floor.

$$
\lfloor a \rfloor = \text{the greatest integer that is smaller than }a
$$

$$
\lceil a \rceil = \text{the least integer that is greater than }a
$$

---

Since you seem to be really confused about this answer from the book, I will write a little bit more about it.

Here is how you should have worked out this proof:

1) Suppose $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil = b$ some integer, then it suffices to show that $\lfloor \frac{n - 1}{k} \rfloor = b - 1$;

2) What conditions do I get from my assumption $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil = b$?

3) Will conditions I get from 2) imply that $\lfloor \frac{n - 1}{k} \rfloor = b - 1$?

Comment: where are the subtraction of 1 coming from like (b-1) or n-1? Also, why is k being multiplied by b and b-1?

Comment: @Kasper-34  each of the intervals look like $((b-1)k, bk]$ for some integer $b$, that is where the $b - 1$ comes from.

Comment: @Kasper-34 And the $n - 1$ is a part in the equation. The inequality for $n - 1$ comes from the following fact: if $m$ and $n$ are integers, $m > n$, then $m \geq n + 1$.

Comment: It seems too abstract for me at the moment. I appreciate the reply but I think I'll ask my professor about it.

Comment: @SecretMath. Amazing explanation. So the real line is divided into intervals. But I have few questions: 1) why the intervals are closed from one side and open from the other, e.g. $(0,k]$? 2) I got the first part $(b−1)k \lt n \le bk$, but I am still not sure why the equality was swapped to the left side in  $(b−1)k \le n-1 \lt bk$